# How well-known is the word 'wheelie'?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

I'm curious how popular the word 'wheelie' is among native speakers. I'm a foreign citizen and came across it accidentally.

For the curious, *wheelie* means when you maneuver your bike/bicycle to roll on one wheel only.

Comment: +1 for fond memories: http://www.google.com/images?q=raleigh+choper

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say *wheelie* is very well known in the U.S. Most kids grow up doing wheelies on their bikes or watching someone do it.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelie), wheelies have been widely known since at least 1943, and they were further popularized by Evel Knievel.

Comment: I agree that "wheelie" is well known in the U.S.

Comment: I think it is well know on this side, too.

Comment: I grew up in the UK and it was very common there (both in London and in Yorkshire).  As far as I know it’s the main word for that bike trick all around the UK (and I think also Australia and Canada), so anyone who grew up with kids on bikes around will know it.

Comment: Certainly, anybody who watches EEEVEEEEL KA-NIEEEVEEEL would know what a wheelie is. That's actually one of the *safest* things he's done, FWIW. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Wheelie is well known in Australia. BTW: the opposite of a wheelie is a stoppie, that is when you apply the brakes sufficiently hard to life the rear-wheel off the ground. Tends to apply more for motorcycles.